# Change of colors in compare.matrix command in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to change the **colors** for the `compare.matrix` command in `r`, but the error is always the same:

```
Error in image.default(x = mids, y = mids, z = mdata, col = c(heat.colors(10)[10:1]),  : 
formal argument "col" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

My code is very simple:

```
compare.matrix(current,ech_b1,nbins=40)
```

and some of my attempts are:

```
compare.matrix(current,ech_b1,nbins=40,col=c(grey.colors(5)))
compare.matrix(current,ech_b1,nbins=40,col=c(grey.colors(10)[10:1]))
```

Comment: welcome to SO! Please include `library()` for the package containing `compare.matrix()` and also make your issue reproducible by including the objects in your example. See, e.g., `dput(current)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `compare.matrix()` from the `SDMTools` package, the color arguments appear to be hard-coded into the function, so you'll need to redefine the function in order to make them flexible:

```
# this shows you the code in the console
SDMTools::compare.matrix
function(x,y,nbins,...){
        #---- preceding code snipped ----#
        suppressWarnings(image(x=mids, y=mids, z=mdata, col=c(heat.colors(10)[10:1]),...))
        #overlay contours
        contour(x=mids, y=mids, z=mdata,  col="black", lty="solid", add=TRUE,...)
    }
```

So you can make a new one like so, but bummer, there are two functions using the ellipsis that have a `col` argument predefined. If you'll only be using extra args to `image()` and not to `contour()`, this is cheap and easy.

```
my.compare.matrix <- function(x,y,nbins,...){
    #---- preceding code snipped ----#
    suppressWarnings(image(x=mids, y=mids, z=mdata,...))
    #overlay contours
    contour(x=mids, y=mids, z=mdata,  col="black", lty="solid", add=TRUE)
}
```

If, however, you want to use `...` for both internal calls, then the only way I know of to avoid confusion about redundant argument names is to do something like:

```
my.compare.matrix <- function(x,y,nbins,
        image.args = list(col=c(heat.colors(10)[10:1])),
        contour.args = list(col="black", lty="solid")){
    #---- preceding code snipped ----#
    contour.args[[x]] <- contour.args[[y]] <- image.args[[x]] <- image.args[[y]] <- mids
    contour.args[[z]] <- image.args[[z]] <- mdata
    suppressWarnings(do.call(image, image.args))
    #overlay contours
    do.call(contour, contour.args)
}
```

Decomposing this change: instead of `...` make a named list of arguments, where the previous hard codes are now defaults. You can then change these items by renaming them in the list or adding to the list. This could be more elegant on the user side, but it gets the job done. Both of the above modifications are untested, but should get you there, and this is all prefaced by my above comment. There may be some other problem that cannot be detected by SO Samaritans because you didn't specify the package or the data.